# How to set headers in DRF's APIClient() delete() request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-unittest

When running tests, I'd like to create and then delete some resources. Access to the target server requires authenticating with a token.

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

(...)

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_creation_and_deletion(self):
        payload = {"key": "value"}

        # This works, but it's handled by a custom create() method from views.py:
        res = self.client.post(<url>, payload)
        (...)

        # This doesn't work, no custom delete() method is defined anywhere:
        tar_headers = {"private-token": "<token>"}
        res2 = self.client.delete(res.data["target_resource_url"], headers=tar_headers)

        # Either this doesn't work:
        self.client.headers.update(tar_headers)
        res3 = self.client.delete(res.data["target_resource_url"])
```

Printing `res2` gives the following output:

```py
<HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html">
```

Calling `res3` gives an error:

```py
AttributeError: 'APIClient' object has no attribute 'headers'
```

Deletion requests sent towards `target_resource_url` from e.g. Postman work fine as long as token is given in headers.

How to approach this issue?

Comment: Does this help you? [DRF headers & authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#headers-authentication)

Comment: `HTTPBasicAuth` requires username and password and I think it doesn't accept any other values, so it couldn't be applied here.

Comment: it is not about the `HTTPBasicAuth` , its about simply adding **`client.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})`**

Comment: It throws an error, I just added it as `res3` in the markup above, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to authenticate with a `Private-Token` while requesting deletion via `APIClient()`. But instead, the good old `requests` library can be used:

```py
import requests

HEADERS = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': <TOKEN>}

res = ...
if "api_link" in res.data:
    requests.delete(res.data["api_link"], headers=HEADERS)
```